# C# Call Event Handler Dynamic

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to save all the controls from one WebForm using a serialized Dictionary (controlId - string, controlValue - string). Next i want to deserialize that Dictionary and dynamically fill the controls with their values.

The problem is that some of my controls have AutoPostBack true and also event handlers. **Is there a way to dynamically call these event handlers?** I want to avoid another switch by control's id.

Ex:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in dict)
{
    Control c = findControlRecursive(Page, kvp.Key);
    if (c != null)
    {
        switch (c.GetType().Name)
        {
            case "TextBox":
                ((TextBox)c).Text = kvp.Value;
                if (((TextBox)c).AutoPostBack) .......
```

EDIT:

Let's say that I have 10 different forms. each has about 50 controls. I want to add/edit a set of data. I try to avoid tables in database with columns for each control, that's why I want to use serialization.

Comment: All these controls and their values are available to you on the postback anyway?

Comment: Yes... I retrieve the serialized dictionary from database and i deserialize it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it later... i was looking for:

if (((TextBox)c).AutoPostBack) **(c as IPostBackDataHandler).RaisePostDataChangedEvent();**

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view you are trying to reinvent a wheel.  ASP.NET provides the WebUserControl class which can be used on different pages and works as a container for a set of controls.  You can define event handlers for these controls and they will be called appropriately regardless the page you are using them on.

So, I would suggest that you use the WebUserControl based approach without serializing / deserializing controls.  This is an easy and  effective solution.

Comment: this form/page has lots of controls... i want to save their values in a database and then to load them back, but without creating tables with columns for each field...

Comment: OK, if so, UserControl is a way to go.  You can set control values manually and events will work properly :).  You should just keep all your controls on the UserControl.

Comment: i don't think UserControl is what i need... i need to have these values in a database

Comment: Page.aspx?Id=125 should fill my form with values from database. I try to avoid creating a table(Id, Control1, Control2, Control3... Control50), that's why i was thinking at dynamic serialize the entire form, dynamic deserialize it and fill the form. I managed to fill the controls with their values, but some of those controls have eventhandlers that should fire once they have values. (sorry for my english)

Comment: ...can you tell me how to obtain information about event handlers associated with controls? for example, the event name a DropDownList should fire on SelectedIndexChanged